# Jquery traversing between pages

Tags: jquery

I go from `page1-page2-page3-page4` and on `page4` after performing tasks I use the `mobile.changepage(#...)` to come back to `page 3`. Now, when I use the `back button` on the page, from `page3` it goes to `page4` then `page3-page2-page1`. I need it to be `page3-page2-page1`.

Comment: Do you mean the browser's back button or some back button that is present on the page?

Comment: I mean the button present on the page.

Comment: Then you should probably tell us what code gets executed in that back button, as well as what you have tried so far to fix it. And please edit the question to include this information (people new to this question should not have to read all the comments to get the full picture).